# Scala Recursive Function with patterns

Tags: scala

When creating a function with recursion on Pattern matching its throws the below error, but when created with a method it works fine. Can you please help me understand.

```
val power: (Int, Int) => Int = (base: Int, exp: Int) => {
    exp match {
        case 0 => 1
        case 1 => `base`
        case e => `base` * power(`base`, e - 1) 
    }
}
```

The code above shows produces the error: "Forward reference extends over definition of value". But the code below works fine:

```
def func1(base: Int, exp: Int): Int = {
    exp match {
        case 0 => 1
        case 1 => `base`
        case e => `base` * func1(`base`, e - 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the error when i tried to run it via Eclipse Scala Worksheet,but the same code works fine on scala REPL.Thanks jwvh

Comment: I've tested it on a Scala worksheet on IntelliJ IDEA 14 and 15EAP. It works so I guess it's just Eclipse Scala worksheet issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `lazy` to the front of the `val` in order that the expression is set rather than executed. Then when it is executed by calling it, it will already have been set.